# How can i write \\\ in nsstring?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I must write "\\\" in my nsstring. I tried @"\\\" But it didn't work well. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try `@"\\\\\\"`? You need to escape each of the slashes with another slash, because `\` is used as an escape character, in sequences such as `\n` for new line.

Answer (score 1):

Double the backslashes. Each one is an escape character, so to write a single `\` you must write `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape each individual backslash. Use `@"\\\\\\"`  in the above code. This will escape each individual backslash.

Answer (score 0):

If you want three \ you have to multiply it by to. So six \